# Best solution to sort different structs that have a common field

Tags: sorting, go

I have struct types like

```
type A struct {
    Name string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    ...
}

type B struct {
    Title string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    ...
}

type C struct {
    Message string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    ...
}
```

And a generic slice

```
var result []interface{}
```

containing A, B and C elements (and more to come in the future)

I want to sort that slice by 'CreatedAt'.

What is the best solution ? I want to avoid checking types or casting...

Comment: Do `A` and `B` share an interface? How is this different than sorting values in general?

Comment: @JimB Maybe he is asking something generic to sort different structs that have a common field

Comment: @NidhinDavid Yes that the point

Comment: @guillaume06 how are A and B stored in your slice? what does the slice look like?

Comment: @guillaume06: do you want "generic", meaning you want to use reflection to find `CreatedAt` on any type? What prevents you from you just asserting type `A` or `B`?

Comment: the "best" solution is arguable. What have you tried?

Comment: @jimB Yes... just curious to know what could be the most elegant solution

Comment: @guillaume06: the usual solution is to just type switch or assert the the types you have. Using reflection is never "elegant"

Comment: Probably the smoothest would be to define an interface with a method that returns the `CreatedAt` date, and make your slice a slice of that interface so you can sort on the method return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you can have a slice containing both of these types anyway is that the slice contains some interface that is implemented by both types (including `interface{}`).

You will probably want to use the `sort` package and implement `sort.Interface` on your slice.  The solution gets a little verbose, but makes good sense:

```
type Creation interface {
    GetCreated() time.Time
}

type A struct {
    Name      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

func (a *A) GetCreated() time.Time {
    return a.CreatedAt
}

func (a *A) String() string {
    return a.Name
}

type B struct {
    Title     string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

func (b *B) GetCreated() time.Time {
    return b.CreatedAt
}

func (b *B) String() string {
    return b.Title
}

type AorB []Creation

func (x AorB) Len() int {
    return len(x)
}

func (x AorB) Less(i, j int) bool {
    // to change the sort order, use After instead of Before
    return x[i].GetCreated().Before(x[j].GetCreated())
}

func (x AorB) Swap(i, j int) {
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
}

func main() {
    a := &A{"A", time.Now()}
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    b := &B{"B", time.Now()}
    aOrB := AorB{b, a}

    fmt.Println(aOrB)
    // [B A]

    sort.Stable(aOrB)

    fmt.Println(aOrB)
    // [A B]
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could put the CreatedAt field in another structure and embed that in each of your types.  That would allow you to define GetCreated once and have the implementation (and field definition) shared across your structures, instead of duplicating it on each type.